# Calling Win Batch file with Whitespace in Path from another Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

On a Windows 2012 Server machine I want to call a batch file from a wrapper batch file. The path to the called batch file contains a space, it's in `M:\Programs\Epic Games\4.12\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\RunUAT.bat`. So my wrapper batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
call "%1\%2\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\RunUAT.bat"
```

And I am calling that wrapper like this from the command line:

```
Wrapper.bat "M:\Programs\Epic Games" 4.12
```

But this leads to the following error:

```
'""M:\Programs\Epic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried it with and without the `call` in the wrapper, but the result is the same.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) or `call /?`:

> If Command Extensions are enabled …
>
> `%~1`         - expands `%1` removing any surrounding quotes (`"`)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
call "%~1\%~2\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\RunUAT.bat"
```